# flutter firebase fire authentication - error since update

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Since I have updated flutter and Android Studio, I am getting an error with a code which was working fine previously. I have done some research but have not find the right solution. Please, can you help me to solve this? Many thanks

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                User user = snapshot.data; // error A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'User'.
                if (user == null) {
                  return LoginPageTest();

``
```

Comment: what Flutter and Android Studio version are you using?

Comment: Flutter 2.2.1
A Studio 4.2.1

Answer (score 2):

You should have activated null safety, so `User user` is declared to not accept null, but `snapshot.data` can be null so is incompatible. You can declase user as nullable, adding a ?, like bellow:

```
User? user = snapshot.data;
```

Comment: yes. the same "A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'User?"

Comment: Hmm because data is not an instance of User, maybe you can try this way? snapshot.data as User

Comment: It works. Error has disappeared. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define `StreamBuilder` data type. By default it `Object?` (with null safety). Here is your updated code, try this

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return StreamBuilder<User?>(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                User? user = snapshot.data;                    
                if (user == null) {
                  return LoginPageTest();

``
```